# Run a Docker service multiple times in parallel to take advantage of a computer with multiple CPU cores

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a small Python application which is packed into a [compose](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md) file as an `app` and a `db` service.

The job of the `app` service is to run some spatial computations using data from the `db` (PostgreSQL) and writing some results in that same database along with some files on disk. For the latter point, I'm using a bind mount as a volume, so that the file are saved on the host machine.

The problem I'm facing is that, based on a sample dataset, I estimated the time to finish the computations on all the records of the database to roughly 1 year...

I also noticed that the Python scripts of the app are only using one CPU core at a time. This is fine, because I'm not used to parallel programming, and also because I rely on a third party software to run some analysis, and that piece of software is also mono-threaded.

On the other hand, I have access to a multi CPU-cores machine (60x). I noticed that each time I start my compose file, only one CPU core is active.

Hence my naive question; could I take advantage of the dockerization to run the same `app` service as many time there are available CPU on that machine (or a bit less maybe)?
Please notice that the `db` service can only be there once and shared to these multiple same `app` services.

If yes, how to do that properly and efficiently?

I was thinking of "copy-pasting" the `app` service 50 times in the compose file, giving it each time another name but this is probably awfully ugly(!). There should be better ways of doing that... From the host machine maybe? Any hints are appreciated. I'm not a docker expert.

Comment: The big question mark is if the application supports that (most likely not). If it doesn't all your workers will process the same data and you will just get 60 copies of the same results...

Comment: I won't enter into the details, but I'm using a `random()` SQL sub-selection so that it only process a small batch of records at a time. It will also check that a record was not already processed using a `created` field, and skip it if necessary. It's doing that in an infinite loop, unless there are no more records to process. It's not super clean but it's working fine. So I'm pretty sure it can be run many times in parallel. At least, I'd like to give it a try...

Comment: Then your method with copy-paste might actually work! I would probably have used Docker without compose and kicked off 50 instances in a loop with bash, but the end result should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

In short, this is possible by using the `--scale` option of `docker-compose up`:

```
docker-compose up --scale app=50 app
```

Doc: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/

This will start 50 instances of the `app` service.

Of course, the application must be designed to be run in parallel if it accesses a unique database in order to avoid troubles.

Versionning information on Ubuntu 18.04 (`5.4.0-81-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux`):

```
$ docker-compose --version
dockedocker-compose version 1.27.4, build 40524192

$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d
```

Comment: Footnote:, those are not actual services, only swarm can do that.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I feel like I misunderstood sometime when reading your comment and I'd like to figure it out. Aren't the `services:` blocks in a Compose file actual services? This would be strange because the name tells it to me!

Comment: They are run as normal containers. Compose authors just used the name service in confusing fashion. Although, if you use that compose file with swarm, they will be real services. Just as if you would do `docker service create ...`. But for that capability, you need to have [swarm mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) enabled and also use the compose file with `docker stack deploy --compose-file myfile.yaml`. So you don't even need to have compose installed in that instance. If run with compose, they will never be real services.

Comment: Oh, thank you for your detailed explanations. I'll go study more about that swarm mode then. :-)